# Serialize and Deserialize JSON on model fields

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My model looks like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public JObject Address { get; set; }

    }
```

As you can see, `Address` is a **jsonb** column. Right now, the client has to turn its contents into JSON for the server to accept it, and parse the JSON contents when it retrieves it from the server. What is an elegant approach to have the server take care of this work?

Comment: OK, so Person class is used to communication with server? What change is expected? On client side or server side?

Comment: @Hostel the Person class represents the model for a db table. The table has an "Address" column which expects json. I'd like the server to automatically take care of the JSON conversion for the column as opposed to having the client do it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found was to add something like this to my `DbContext`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(e => e.Address)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()}),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(v,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()})
            );
```